# Update not redirecting to show - missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've taken a look at the other questions about missing templates, but their mistakes don't seem to be the case here. e.g. I don't have 
*remote: true* in my form.

I have a form to update an Inspection:

```
<%= simple_form_for @inspection , :html => {  multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :building_id, @building.id %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
      <div class="form-group select optional inspection_building">
        <label class="select optional control-label" for="inspection_building_id">Building: </label>
         <%= @building.name %>
      </div>

     <div class="form-group select optional inspection_building">
        <label class="select optional control-label" for="inspection_building_id">Bot: </label>
        <%= Inspection::BOTS[0] %>
     </div>
     <%= f.input :inspection_label %>
     <%= f.input :notes %>

    <div class="controls form-group integer required">
        <div>
            <%= f.input :capture_date, as: :date, html5: true, label: "Capture Date of Inspection Images" %>
        </div>
    </div>



    <% if true #if @inspection.new_record? #only show for new inspections %>
        <%= render 'attach_image_meta_files' %>

        <br>

        <div class="controls form-group integer required">
            <label class="integer required control-label" for="layout_type">What Excel file Layout, Filip?</label>
            <div>
            <%= select_tag :layout_type,
               options_for_select(%w[New Old])              %>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="controls form-group integer required">
            <label class="integer required control-label" for="image_file_prefex">Image File Prefex? (this combined the the Excel file Image Number needs to match the image file names uploaded)</label>
            <div>
                <%= text_field_tag :image_file_prefex, 'DSC_', class: 'required form-control' %>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="controls form-group integer required">
            <label class="integer required control-label" for="first_row_of_data">First Row of Data?</label>
            <div>
                <%= number_field_tag :first_row_of_data, 3, in: 1..10, class: 'numeric integer required form-control' %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="controls form-group integer required">
            <label class="integer required control-label" for="top_floor">What is the Top Floor of the Building (what floor number do you want the Roof to be)?</label>
            <div>
                <%= number_field_tag :top_floor, 1, in: 1..100, class: 'numeric integer required form-control' %>
            </div>
        </div>

    <% end %>
 </div>
<br>
<span id="loading-msg" class="text-center display_loading"  style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; color:blue; display:none">
            <%= image_tag "ajax-loader.gif",  alt: "loading", id: "loading_image", class: "center-block" %>Uploading Images and Processing.  This will take a while!
</span>
<script>
$(".display_loading").on("click", function() {
           $('#loading-msg').show();
    })
</script>

  <div class="form-actions">


    <% if @inspection.new_record? #only show for new inspections %>
        <%= f.button :button,  class: 'btn btn-success display_loading' do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> Upload and Process Inspection Files
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
         <%= f.button :submit,  class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the controller:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @inspection.update(inspection_params)

               Thread.new do
                      process_image_and_excel_metadata_files

                end

            format.html { redirect_to @inspection,
                      notice: 'Inspection was successfully Updated. Images are being Processed in the background. ~1 minute per 50 files' } and return


      else
        format.html { render :edit }

      end
    end
  end
```

So it should redirect to the show view (which exists, of course).

Instead, it tries to find inspections/update and fails:

> Missing template inspections/update, application/update with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb,
>   :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.

EDIT- Here's my routes.rb:

```
RailsApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :issues    # later remove this
  resources :issue_types
  resources :inspection_images

  resources :buildings do
    resources :elevations
    resources :user_buildings
  end
  resources :importer

  resources :inspections do
    get 'apply'
    resources :image_reviews, only: :index
    resources :issue_reviews, only: :index
  end
  resources :image_reviews, only: [ :show, :edit, :update] do
     resources :issues
     get 'print_issues'
     post 'print_issues'
  end
  get 'inspections/:inspection_id/image_reviews(/:elevation_id)', to: 'image_reviews#index'
  get 'inspections/:inspection_id/reorder/:drop_id', to: 'image_reviews#reorder', as: 'drop_reorder'


  # authenticated :user.admin do
  #   root :to => "base#index"
  # end

  root "buildings#index"

  get "user_buildings/:building_id/add_to_building" => 'user_buildings#add_to_building', :as => :add_to_building



  namespace :admin do
    root "base#index"
    resources :users
  end

  devise_for :users

end
```

Comment: Geleia, can you please share your routes.rb?

Comment: @David Of course. I've added it to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
format.html { redirect_to @inspection,
notice: 'Inspection was successfully Updated. Images are being Processed in the background. ~1 minute per 50 files' } and return
```

should be

```
format.html { redirect_to @inspection,
notice: 'Inspection was successfully Updated. Images are being Processed in the background. ~1 minute per 50 files' and return }
```

Note the position of the return. Actually the return is unnecessary inside the block, you can leave it out entirely.